# Solutions of $z=\dfrac{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}{\sqrt{-21+20i}+\sqrt{-21-20i}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that the solution of $z=\dfrac{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}{\sqrt{-21+20i}+\sqrt{-21-20i}}$ are $\dfrac{5i}{2}$ and $\dfrac{-2i}{5}$

I know that If I write $\sqrt{-21+20i}=\pm(2+5i)$ and $\sqrt{-21-20i}=\pm(2-5i)$, then I will get the required solutions. But, when I do the following :

\begin{align}
z&=\frac{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}{\sqrt{-21+20i}+\sqrt{-21-20i}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}{\sqrt{-21+20i}+\sqrt{-21-20i}}.\frac{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}{\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i}}\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{-21+20i}-\sqrt{-21-20i})^2}{(\sqrt{-21+20i})^2-(\sqrt{-21-20i})^2}\\
&=\frac{-21+20i-21-20i-2\sqrt{21^2+20^2=841}}{-21+20i+21+20i}\\
&=\frac{-21-\sqrt{841}}{20i}=\frac{-21-29}{20i}=\frac{5i}{2}
\end{align}

Why am I missing the solution $\dfrac{-2i}{5}$ in my attempt ?

If I were to take $\sqrt{841}=-29$ I think I'll get the other solution but, I always considered $\sqrt{x}$ as the +ve square root and $-\sqrt{x}$ the -ve square root of the number $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $841$ has two square roots.

Comment: thats right. but usually mean $\sqrt{x}$, +ve square root of $x$ and $-\sqrt{x}$, -ve square root of $x$ right ?

Comment: But here, we don't. Otherwise the expression on the right has exactly one value.

Comment: @enedil i agree if I consider that I'll get the other solution. But, If I wee to twist the convention here I need to do the same for any problem right ?. I think I am particularly confused about the fact that $\sqrt{x}$ only mean the +ve square root usually.

Comment: @ss1729 But in this specific case, $\sqrt{841}$ actually appears as the product of two complex square roots ($\sqrt{-21+20i}\cdot\sqrt{-21-20i}$), and I don't think you have any issues accepting that _those_ are multivalued.